# Abstract font shape?

Tags: fonts, abstract, shapes

I am writing an article using the following `asme2e` class:

http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/conf-1.6b.html

I want to change the font shape in the abstract. It is *italic*, but I want it in normal font.

Comment: Just don't issue the `\it` command: `\begin{abstract}text\end{abstract}` will not use italics.

Comment: And don't use `\it` even if you *do* want italics! (Use `\itshape` or `\textit{}` instead.)

Answer (score 3):

The model document has

```
\begin{abstract}
{\it This article illustrates preparation of ASME paper using \LaTeX2\raisebox{-.3ex}{$\epsilon$}. An abstract for an ASME paper should be less than 150 words and is normally in italics.}
\end{abstract}
```

Just doing

```
\begin{abstract}
This article illustrates preparation of ASME paper using \LaTeX2\raisebox{-.3ex}{$\epsilon$}. An abstract for an ASME paper should be less than 150 words and is normally in italics.
\end{abstract}
```

will remove the italics.